# firebase images URL don't display in app

Tags: javascript, android, image, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an important problem I need to solve it please
I need to send everyday through firebase database realtime Messages and images and I need to update theme every day but my problem is ( the images don't display in the app , nothing happen ) could you please help me ...

Here is the code

```js
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import static android.R.attr.data;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView Latestone,Msgone;
    ImageView Image1;
    Uri ImaUri;
    URL ImaUrl;




    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference mRootReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();

    DatabaseReference aKidRefernece = firebaseDatabase.getReference("latesttitle1");
    DatabaseReference aChildReference = mRootReference.child("latestmsg1");
    DatabaseReference bKidRefernece = firebaseDatabase.getReference("image1");



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Latestone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latest_title);
        Msgone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latest_msg);
        Image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
        Latestone.setText("Message Body");
        Msgone.setText("Message Title");



    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        aChildReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String message = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Msgone.setText(message);


                aKidRefernece.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String title = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                        Latestone.setText(title);


                        bKidRefernece.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                String image = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

      }
```

[Here is what happen when I open the android App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHSry.png)

[Here is the firebase database discriptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH9Ky.png)

Comment: I think you want this tagged with `java` not, `javascript`

Comment: @brainbolt i need any thing helps me brother , thanks